# Creating a dynamic range, in Excel, using combinations of text in row and column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**What I want to achieve:**

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F *(expected result)* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | *RowTextCOL1* |
| **2** | RowText | 5 | 3 | 0 | 2 | *RowTextCOL2* |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |  | *RowTextCOL4* |

I'm looking for a way to create a dynamic 1-D range by concatenating the text in a row with the text in several columns, where the corresponding data entry > 0.
I'd like to achieve this using only formulas, not VB.

So, in `F1`, I want there to be a dynamic range that extends vertically. The range should contain all possible combinations of the text in the row text cell `A2` and the different texts in the columns `B1:E1`. The dynamic range `F1` should also be filtered to only contain combinations where the data entries `B2:E2` > 0.

**What I have so far:**
I created the following function in `F1`: `=TEXTSPLIT(REPT(CONCAT(A2;B1:E1;".");COLUMNS(B1:E1));;".")`

However this appends the text in all the columns `B1:E1` to the text from the cell `A2`. It also needs to be filtered in some way to only include the combinations where the data entries `B2:E2` > 0.

[image: What I managed to create]

Comment: Try: `=TOCOL(IFS(C2:F2>0,B2&C1:F1),3)`

Comment: This will also work as confirmed by @P.b. --> `=TOCOL(IFS(C2:F2,B2&C1:F1),3)`